# Access object field in a CALLBACK function (WINAPI - C++)

Tags: c++, class, winapi, callback

I'm using the `SetWinEventHook()` function like in the example by MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx.

Like in the example above, to handle events I use the CALLBACK function`HandleWinEvent()`.
I'm pretty new in using this type of function: what I've understood is that this function is called
asynchronously and parameters are passed automatically. 
Now I want to access to the list inside the function. 
I declared this function inside my class:

```
Class Example
{
private: std::list <int> events;
void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, 
                             LONG idObject, LONG idChild, 
                             DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime) 
{
events.add((int)event);
};

void Initialize_Hook()
{
    cout << "Initialization Thread messages..........." << endl;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    g_hook = SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS,  // Range of events (4 to 5).
        NULL,                                          // Handle to DLL.
        HandleWinEvent,                                // The callback.
        0, 0,              // Process and thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); // Flags.
}
}
```

and I simply want to add the event's identifier to my list, but it doesn't recognize `events`. There's a way to make the function know what the list is?
More specifically, I declared the CALLBACK function in the .cpp file, but I have to declare it as `void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(...)` instead of `void CALLBACK Example::HandleWinEvent(...)` as I always do because the second choice gives an error in `SetWinEventHook()`.

Comment: The callback isn't allowed to be an instance method. So ask yourself where it is going to find your instance?

Comment: I don't know. For example I can pass through SetWinEventHook a pointer to the list, but I'm inventing (also because in the prototype there's no pointer to pass). How can I do it?

Comment: Either use a thunk or a single global variable holding your instance

Comment: A global variable for the list? Sorry but I don't know what thunk means.

Comment: Google will tell you what a thunk is in this context. Basically you generate code at runtime that contains the instance pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint provided by @David Heffernan, I decided to declare the list as `static`. Then I wrote a static method to get the list.
In this way, inside the CALLBACK function I could get the reference to the list:

```
private: static std::list <int> events;
std::list <int>& getList() {
return *events;
}
// the callback is now declared in Example.cpp file
void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, 
                             LONG idObject, LONG idChild, 
                             DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime) 
{
Example::getList().add((int)event);
};
```

(I didn't try with `int`, with a list of `Example2` class worked).